# Can't wrap columns in a flexbox flow except under Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I fix the max-height of the "content" div. The code works only under Chrome :/

the "content" div should not expand outside the bottom of the window. the items should wrap to the right.

item1  item4 item7
item2  item5 ...
item3  item6

html

```
  <div class="top">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">

   <div class="left">
     <div class="link">Link</div>
   </div>

   <div class="content">
     <div class="item">Item1</div>
     <div class="item">Item2</div>
     <div class="item">Item3</div>
     <div class="item">Item4</div>
     <div class="item">Item5</div>
     <div class="item">Item6</div>
     <div class="item">Item7</div>
     <div class="item">Item8</div>
     <div class="item">Item9</div>
     <div class="item">Item10</div>
     <div class="item">Item11</div>
     <div class="item">Item12</div>
     <div class="item">Item13</div>
     <div class="item">Item14</div>
     <div class="item">Item15</div>
     <div class="item">Item16</div>
     <div class="item">Item17</div>
     <div class="item">Item18</div>
     <div class="item">Item19</div>
   </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
.main {
  height: 100%;
  max-heigth: 100%; /* not required under chrome, do not works for others */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  background-color: silver;
}
.left {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.content {
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap; /* warp only under Chrome */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L7zzucms/

Comment: Your `max-height` isn't working any where. It's misspelled (in both your question and demo). But I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: It's not working because Chrome isn't requiring you to define a height on the `.content` container. FF, Edge and possibly other browsers need a defined height. https://jsfiddle.net/L7zzucms/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `wrapper` rule to this and it works everywhere (tested on Chrome,Firefox,Edge,IE11)

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7zzucms/7/)

I suppose the `flex: 1` in `content` need a height, other than `flex: 1 1 auto`, from its parent to be able to wrap properly